# How do I get the rating for a source in activerecord-reputation-system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using Twitter's activerecord-reputation-system gem which has been easy to get set up but running into a challenge getting the rating a source provided on a target.

My model looks like this with the user bing the source (the one doing the rating)

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

has_reputation :ratings,
:source => :user,
:aggregated_by => :average
```

I'm able to add ratings for users easily enough with:

```
@item.add_evaluation(:ratings, 3, @user)
```

I can then see if that user has already rated an item with

```
has_evaluation?(:ratings, @user)
```

This returns the boolean.  What I'd like to get is the *value* of the rating that the user gave to that item (not just its existence).  I guess what I want is a has_evaluation_value function or something which doesn't seem to exist that.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can read everything you need on the [GitHub repos README](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system).

```
@item.reputation_for(:ratings)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the average rating for the item (average over all user ratings).  I'm looking for the rating on the item that current_user gave it.  In other words I'd like to show the user the average rating as well as his own personal rating.